# Using stock quote from stock_quote gem as tag from acts_as_taggable gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am using the tags provided by the acts_as_taggable gem.  The posts are what I am tagging.  How could I say something (pseduocode here) like =>

```
if a collection of Posts has a tag with a corresponding StockQuote, display the stock quote
```

So right now I have a Post resource that acts_as_taggable. Here is what my posts index action looks like now:

```
def index
@stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote("symbol")

if params[:tag]
@posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
else
 @posts = Post.order('cached_votes_score desc')
end

end
```

So I would somehow have to iterate through all the @posts tagged_with params[:tag] and compare the tags to stock quotes. And display the quote on the index of all the @posts tagged_with params[:tag] if there is a match.  I am going to try to figure out how to limit each post to have 1 tag soon

How could I use the :tag of a post to access a stock quote if that tag happens to be a stock quote?

Comment: You would increase your chances if you'd describe the mechanism a bit more. Otherwise you risk to restrict the audience to only those who know the gems.

Comment: How do you know if a tag is a stock symbol?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to do something like:

```
@symbols = @post.tag_list
@quotes = StockQuote::Stock.quote(@symbols)
```

Since a post could actually be tagged with multiple symbols you will want to fetch them all at once and then iterate over the result in the view. Something like:

```
<% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
  <%= "#{quote.symbol}: #{quote.ask}" %>
<% end %>
```

I am not familiar with the gems all that much but with quick glance it seems something like this would work.

Also, you phrase the question as if you have a singular instance of a Post but then show your index action which would pull a collection of Posts. The example I provided would work for a singular Post (a user viewing the post's page).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I  was actually looking for the collection of posts (changed the question, sorry), but I might be able to figure it out from this I'm not sure